# IE11 не отображает простой элемент after

Tags: css3, ie11

Всем добрый день.

Подскажите почему не отображается псевдоэлемент after у заголовка (нижняя черточка). Особенность в  том, что в chrome все как нужно, в ie11 на развернутом окне after элемент отображается, как только начинаем менять размер окна элемент пропадает. Если проинспектировать элемент, то он появляется!! Но в инспекторе все стили все равно перечеркнуты.

```css
.title {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 34px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 8.95px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
 position: relative;
  }
.title:after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 81px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -40.5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="title">about</div>
<div class="text">We specialize in contemporary, functional, and stunning websites with design that really brings that "WOW" factor. 
In our design process, we make sure to stay one step ahead of the latest trends, 
never forgetting to abide by key web standards.</div>
```

Скрины для наглядности:
https://prnt.sc/qm98io   где мой элемент?
https://prnt.sc/qm99yp   в инспекторе элемент появился, но в стилях все перечеркнуто

Comment: у вас стили перекрываются, вам в консоли разработчика всё показано.

Comment: Да я это вижу, но не понимаю что их затирает, и почему в инспекторе вдруг этот элемент виден, и на полном экране виден тоже... и почему в других браузерах не перекрывается... Ключевой вопрос где капать причину затирания

Comment: А еще могу заменить цвет даже в зачеркнутых свойствах и это применится https://prnt.sc/qm9g2c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я проверил во всех браузерах - одинаково везде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>about us</h2>
```

Comment: Самый прикол, что в предыдущем таком же блоке все отображается нормально, такой же элемент, но с другим цветом просто https://prnt.sc/qm9hq4

Comment: @Вадим тут уже было такое - человек усирался что ни чего лишнего и код 100% одинаковый - что в вопросе что в коде на компе - а оказалось что совмем разные реализации ...если хотите я посмотрю в тем вивер

Comment: Так а смысл смотреть ТВ если у него в коде явно указано что стили перекрывают друг друга. Даже строчка указана.

Comment: А теперь прикол, что даже на превью видно черточку, пока не кликну на сам значок.. https://prnt.sc/qm9jdb  можно и через tw, напиши в личку если не сложно пожалуйста https://vk.com/daenergy

Comment: @MoloF вот именно о этом я написал ...что 100% что то не так ...или разный код ...

Comment: @Вадим если тебе надо пиши, у меня здесь в кабинете есть email - пиши, мне не надо ...в своё время с меня брали деньги за то что я предлогаю щас на шару

Comment: @MoloF скрин при клике на строчку, возможно я не знаю где смотреть, но в других браузерах то все ок и на полноэкранном режиме все ок https://prnt.sc/qm9kuq  788 строка

Comment: Всем спасибо, почти после часового разбора вместе с @MaximLensky выяснилось, что так получается из за того, что для элемента указано 2 класса: about__title и общий класс для всех заголовков title... Так вот черточка из псевдоэлемента title:after появлялась только при значение height от 2px и более. При это если указать height:2px, то отображался только 1, если 3px - то видно было 2 и тд... При совмещении всего этого в один класс - проблема исчезла.. может кому-то будет полезно... спасибо всем